# Connecting a rococo-local based parachain to a private polkadot-local based relay chain

Tags: parachain, private-network, rococo-local, polkadot-local

I created a polkadot-local based private network relay chain by adding some new keys both in stacking and session sections of the initial polkadot-local spec (I followed this tutorial [Start a private network](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/private-network/) and adapted the logic for polkadot-local spec). My private relay chain is working fine as I see new blocks created from my new polkadot IDs.

Now I would like to link a parachain to my polkadot-local based relay-chain. However the current [cumulus tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/start-relay/) is based on rococo-local chain and I'm wondering if it's possible to mix such spec to link a rococo-local base parachain to polkadot-local base relay chain.

Currently I can see my rococo-local parachain collator node starting but I see it doesn't detect my relay chain nodes :

```
2022-03-08 20:51:19 [Relaychain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x8a7f…e77d), finalized #0 (0x8a7f…e77d), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
```

Can some of you push me some hints on how I can fix this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Try using polkadot-launch and refer to the approach used in this response https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/666/83 and

Comment: Thank you Luke :) . 

I'm trying here to understand the polkadot setup & configurations needed to setup a parachain on a polkadot-local based network manually. 

So while polkadot-launch could help me for sure to setup the overall stuff I've the impression this short cut will not answer my initial questions... Anyway will have a look on it to see if it's help !

Comment: Finally I get the answer of my question : it was a silly network issue. What's sad is that I forced `--bootnodes '...'` options in my collator startup command but it didn't raise any connection issue. As adding this parameter is not explicitely described in the tutorial, I don't know if it make sense to create a ticket so that we get explicit network issue log error ...

Comment: Awesome! This sounds useful to the community. Can you add your answer to this post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I get the answer of my question : it was a silly network issue. What's sad is that I forced --bootnodes '...' options in my collator startup command but it didn't raise any connection issue.

As adding this parameter is not explicitly described in the tutorial, I don't know if it make sense to create a ticket so that we get explicit network issue log error ...

Comment: Please do file an issue on the docs! We can make a note about this, perhaps even an upstream issue should be filed for better logs in substrate on this is possible