# How can you setup your own pre-configured account in a relay/parachain spec?

Tags: private-network, account

I'm going through the different tutorials and I discovered `rococo-local` and `polkadot-local` network and now I would like to hack these networks to define my own pre-configured accounts (ie: replace alice, alice-stash, bob, bob-stash, charlie ... accounts with my own).

I didn't see the appropriate tutorials for such exercise and I begin think I need to add my own spec programmatically.

Can some of you push me some interesting advice and/or documentations link to help me managing that?

Answer (score 3):

Use [polkadot-launch](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-launch) to configure and launch the relay chain and parachain seamlessly. Also refer to this [cumulus](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/start-relay/) tutorial for additional guidance.

Create relevant accounts and session keys for your parachain. The below example would create relevant accounts for the DataHighway parachain.

- Generate the sudo account for the DataHighway parachain `subkey inspect --network datahighway --scheme sr25519 "//$SECRET"`. Generate the secret key from the contents of a file so it is not logged in terminal history `openssl rand -hex 256 > secret_key_file && export SECRET=$( < secret_key_file )`
- Generate accounts for five (5) collators, since the parachain uses Aura `for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do for j in stash controller aura; do subkey inspect --network datahighway --scheme sr25519 "//$SECRET//$i//$j"; done; done; done`
- Add the accounts to the chain_spec.rs of your parachain codebase that is based on the [substrate-parachain-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template). For example, see how the [DataHighway's Spreehafen parachain specification for connecting to rococo](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/blob/main/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L318) uses custom pre-configured accounts and session keys, whereas the [DataHighway's rococo-local parachain specification for connecting to rococo-local](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/blob/main/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L155) just used Substrate's in-built accounts like Alice.

There is a tutorial [here](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/documentation/blob/master/docs/tutorials/tutorials-node-polkadot-launch-datahighway-rococo-local.md) that shows the detailed steps the DataHighway team took to connect their parachain to the rococo-local relay chain.

Comment: Thank you Luke, I will look the way DataHighway's setup its parachain spec. Just to clarify : I'm looking a way to customize the relay chain accounts and not only parachain...

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned

> *"... pre-configured accounts (ie: replace alice, alice-stash, bob, bob-stash, charlie ..."*

Do you mean these accounts?

[image]

Assuming you cloned the **Substrate Node Template** repository, you could find them at [node/src/chain_spec.rs](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/node/src/chain_spec.rs).

In the [`testnet_genesis`](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/c962ed17139322f99d25ed5631ddbb5bbbced2a2/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L140) function, you can see how the list of tuples (AccountId, Balance) is created.

```
/// Configure initial storage state for FRAME modules.
fn testnet_genesis(
    ...
    endowed_accounts: Vec<AccountId>,
    ...
) -> GenesisConfig {
    GenesisConfig {
        ...

        balances: BalancesConfig {
            // Configure endowed accounts with initial balance of 1 << 60.
            balances: endowed_accounts.iter().cloned().map(|k| (k, 1 << 60)).collect(),
        },

        ...
    }
}
```

Where `k` is an account_id from the `endowed_accounts` vector, and
`1<<60` is the 1.1529x10^18 balance amount you see in the image above.

You could also notice that `testnet_genesis` is called in `development_config` and `local_testnet_config` functions. And how the accounts are generated with `get_account_id_from_seed`.